# How do you change the message in a rosbag. For eg. from string to float

Tags: ros, bagfile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you change the message in a rosbag. For eg. from string to float

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240433/how-do-you-change-the-message-in-a-rosbag.-for-eg.-from-string-to-float/) by [chezzydc10](https://answers.ros.org/users/27598/chezzydc10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can migrate messages in your rosbag. Let's say you have a custom message which had a string in it but in a recent version it changed to a float. Given the old message definition and the new, you can create a rule file automatically and adapt it to tell it how to transform the string correctly. Then you can run `rosbag fix` and it does all the magic conversion for you. Have a look at the [rosbag migration tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/migration).

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1